# how to find the specific name in DB from search textbox?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a textbox that stands as a search box:
Here is my code example:

```
    Dim txt As String = txt_find.Text
    query = "SELECT empID AS 'ID', fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname AS 'Name' FROM empInfo "
    query &= "WHERE empID LIKE '%" & txt & "%' OR fname LIKE '%" & txt & "%' OR lname LIKE '%" & txt & "%' OR mname LIKE '%" & txt & "%'"
```

It returns the correct value if the user entered just first name or  last name of the employee.
Example:
Input: 28 Or Dennis Or Smith

But when the user Inputs the full name(e.g. Dennis Smith) the result returns nothing.

how should it be done?.

Comment: my suggestion is that its better to create 2 search box for name.
devided into 'FirstName' and 'LastName'
so that the user can easily identify that if she/he wants to find the user he/she must type the last and first name i a different textbox.

eg. user input Dennis Smith for whole name?
how about he/she input Smith Dennis?

Comment: if you use 1 text search the firstname and lastname must be in 1 field in database. :) its only a suggestion.

Comment: Oh my bad :(  didn't see this loophole okay.

Comment: in your program you must inform the user that he/she typing is for lastname or firstname. in your eg. Dennis Smith. Dennis is what? a lastname, a firstname? or what? so you will get hard to find what is the user want to find. but if there is 2 or more textbox (important fields only) the user can easily know that she/he is finding a name like this or last name like this..

Comment: I'm just thinking about the example search bar on facebook. there's only one search box then you can search anything, from firstname first or lastname first or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 "where Empid like '%" & txt & "%' OR  replace(fname + mname + lname,' ','') like replace('%" & txt & "%',' ', '')"
```

So if you enter 'Dennis Smith' or 'DennisSmith' it will catch the resultant rows

Comment: do this really work? it returns no value for me. its just the same on my example query, it has rows when firstname or last name is entered

Comment: yes, it worked for me.  This is the whole query : "select * from Empinfo where Empid like '%" + txt + "%' or replace(fname + mname + lname,' ','') like replace('% " + txt + "%',' ', '')"  .

Comment: try this in SQL Server query window and see what result you are getting. select * from EmpInfo where Empid like '%Dennis Smith%' or replace(fname + mname+lname,' ','') like replace('% Dennis Smith %',' ', '')

Comment: Ohh I see. I just removed `mname` from `replace(fname + mname + lname,' ','')` .. it works actually fine .thanks! because dennis smith doesn't have middle name. oh, I won't include the mname in the search .. that solves my problem and shortens my query

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
"WHERE fname+' '+lname like '%" & txt & "' OR  fname+' '+mname+' '+lname like '%" & txt & "'"
```

That's just the idea, you just have to include there the possible name formats like *LastName, FirstName MiddleName* or if you can think of more, the better you can handle your search.

Comment: its just make your query longer and longer. there is a better way. just creat a 2 or more textbox for search to easy and good type of searching

Comment: so what if the search criteria expands? he will create a new textbox for each of those search criteria/fields?

Comment: yah. he need to do that. so that the user can identify what is the field he/she want to find.

Comment: possible formats? eg. in 1 = firstname, 2= middlename, 3= lastname then you are saying that he must add this formats 123, 132, 213, 321, 312, 231, see? how many formats can you have? very long query, ahaha

Comment: If you _think_ for just a little bit, the combinations are not that much. 231? Middlename Lastname Firstname? Have you tried searching a name starting with its middlename? Sheesh.. =_=

Comment: I made my query long, but it doesn't matter as long as i achieved what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go like this.

```
"WHERE LastName like '%" & LastName.text & "%' OR fname LIKE '%" & FirstName.text & "%'" and so on.
```

just use the important fields in searching. firstname or lastname will do.